# Can anyone explain me this code in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone explain me the `logic` behind this code?.

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email)
    = :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first
end
```

I am whole new to the `ruby/rails community`, i am not able to understand what is **returned** by the function and what overall this function does?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a part from a rails activerecord model.

it is a class method that returns the first record that meets the given conditions provided as:

- `warden_conditions`
- *the downcased username or email must be equal to* `signin.downcase`

the SQL equivalent should be

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE conditions_to_sql AND lower(username) = a_value OR lower(email) = a_value limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this part of code. where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email)
    = :value", { :value => signin.downcase }]).first

Comment: @theJava I just did, `where` takes either a hash or a an SQL like argument. Chaining two `where`s performs a logical `AND`. The result is described in the SQL equivalent I provide

Comment: I did get the sql query, but some how i am missing the code logic al together. should it not be select condition from items where.

Comment: `where({a: 1, b: 2})` translates to `WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2`.
What this method does is get the records that meet the `warden_conditions` criteria as well as the ones for the `username` or `email`.

Comment: Thanks, one final question. what does this do in the condition { :value => signin.downcase }

Comment: @theJava `{ :value => signin.downcase }` is using a named placeholder for the query, see [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)

Comment: `where(["attribute_1 = :a OR attribute_2 = :a", { a: 123 }])` translates to `WHERE attribute_1 = 123 OR attribute_2 = 123`. It is a way to provide a variable to the ActiveRecord query multiple times without much repetition

Comment: SELECT * FROM items WHERE conditions_to_sql what is conditions_to_sql here?.

Answer (score 2):

What is returned is an active record relation - in this case, a single record.  Because the method starts with `self`, it's a class method, which means it does not operate on a single instance, but rather 'speaks for the entire class'.  `where`, when used bare like this, implies that it operates on self, which again, is the class.

Short answer: It returns the first record from the table represented by this class, that matches the SQL conditions that were passed, and the authorization conditions you see after the conditions.