# Devise `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

My two methods using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

**Method1**

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email)
    = :value", {:value => signin.downcase }]).first
end
```

**Method2**

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  login = conditions.delete(:signin)
  where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = 
    :value", {:value => login.strip.downcase }]).first
end
```

My questions:

1. What does this code perform/do? `login = conditions.delete(:signin)`
2. Without the above code I get an error `undefined local variable or method signin`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain me this code in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049476/can-anyone-explain-me-this-code-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

The following answers question `1)`—specifically `A)` and `B)` below. The following code is an example and does not mirror the actual methods or arguments generated by Devise:

*Here: the `Hash` contains `:signin` key-value pair and other valid `ActiveRecord`'s `#where` syntax
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where*

```
devise_conditions = {:signin => "cool@gmail.com", :deleted => false, :role => 'basic'} 
#=> {:signin=>"cool@gmail.com", :deleted => false, :role => 'basic'}
```

*This duplicates original argument to prevent modification in order to use it in subsequent methods or queries
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup*

```
conditions = devise_conditions.dup 
#=> {:signin=>"cool@gmail.com", :deleted => false, :role => 'basic'}
```

*Here, the code: **A)** deletes the `:signin` key-pair from the `Hash`; and 
**B)** assigns new variable `signin` with value of `:signin` key-pair from `Hash`
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete*

```
signin = conditions.delete(:signin) 
#=> "cool@gmail.com"
```

*The immediately above code could be rewritten to clarify both operations using additional "Element Reference" of `Hash`
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D*

```
signin = conditions[:signin]
#=> "cool@gmail.com"

conditions.delete(:signin)
#=> "cool@gmail.com" # deleted value from Hash is returned

conditions
#=> {:deleted => false, :role => 'basic'}
```

*The method's original argument has been preserved by using `dup`*

```
devise_conditions 
#=> {:signin=>"cool@gmail.com", :deleted => false, :role => 'basic'}
```

---

The following answers question `2)`:

**Method1** does not create a variable `signin`. `undefined local variable or method signin` results from no `signin` variable being created when the code which creates it is removed.

**Method2** creates a variable `login` which has the value from the original `Hash` named `conditions` with the key `:signin`.

Answer (score 0):

1. This deletes `signin` key from `conditions` hash and assigns its value to `login` local variable.

Answer (score 0):

2.. I guess you mean that `signin` is not defined in `find_first_by_auth_conditions`? Then I also guess that `signin` is an attribute of `warden_conditions` so you can try: `warden_conditions.signin`.